# input form with vertical align on Bootstrap 3.0

Tags: html, input, twitter-bootstrap-3, label, vertical-alignment

I have two situations with input forms where I can't align vertically text and fields. I tried display:inline, display:inline-block, display:table-cell, and vertical-align with text-bottom and bottom, but without good results. In the first, the problem is with label (both should be align in the bottom, together the field), in the second the problem is the last radiobox and its label. You can view the problem below. It should be align with the two second radiobox and labels (top align). The align should run in mobile and desktop sizes.

```css
.height-form-home{
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: text-bottom;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<form class="form" role="form">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5 vbottom" >
      <label  class="height-form-home" for="email"> Wordwo do Wordwoe</label><br/>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-7 vbottom" >
        <label  for="pwd" class="height-form-home" >Word/Word Wordwordword
        ou wordwordwordw wordw</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="text">
    </div></div>
   <br/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
       
  </form>
     <br/><br/>
     <form role="form">
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">Wordword<br/>Wordwor
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">Wordwordwo<br/>Wordword
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">Word<br/>
    </label>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add on your form class the 'form-inline'
On mobile screen size, it will go vertical

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<form class="form-inline" role="form">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" >
      <label for="email"> Wordwo do Wordwoe</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" >
        <label  for="pwd" >Word/Word Wordwordword
        </label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="text">
    </div></div>
   <br/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
       
  </form>
     <br/><br/>
     <form class="form-inline" role="form">
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">Wordword<br/>Wordwor
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">Wordwordwo<br/>Wordword
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio">Word<br/>
    </label>
  </form>
```

A clean example is

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">

  <form class="form-inline" role="form">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
    </div>
    
  </form>
</div>
```